# flask request.json with custom mimetype

Tags: python, json, flask

My api requires `application/vnd.api+json` to be the sole mimetype for all interaction.

If I `POST` to an endpoint with the header `Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json`, I examine the `request` object and `request.json` is `None`.

On the other hand, POSTing the same data with the standard `Content-Type: application/json` populates the `request.json` attr with the data I need.

What are my options to populate `request.json` with the data I need when using a custom mimetype? Subclassing request? Setting some parameter on the application instance?

Comment: From my answer on the duplicate: *Flask 0.10 added the `request.get_json()` method, and you should use that method instead of the `.json` property. You can tell the method to skip the content type requirement by setting `force=True`.*

Comment: thanks. sorry I missed the duplicate. Not-So-Hypothetical-Follow-Up: What if I am in a production environment with Flask 0.9 and upgrading third-party is not possible right now :)? Can you recommend any workaround?

Comment: Use `json.loads(request.data)` in that case.